# Pork: sirloin vs tenderloin. Which one is most tender?

Tags: meat, pork, roast, cut-of-meat

What is the difference between pork sirloin and port tenderloin?

I usually buy center cut pork chops and may buy one due to the sale price this week.

Answer (score 3):

Preparation is key, as with most meals. The difference (in tenderness) between a pork sirloin and a pork tenderloin is relatively minor but the tenderloin is generally more tender (as the name implies). In this diagram you can see that they are adjoining cuts from the same primal cut (the Loin). Once you start preparing these cuts the final dish may result in sirloin that has been rendered more tender than the tenderloin. A slow-roasted sirloin may end up 'more tender' than braised tenderloin.

[image]